# Python - identifying if integer is a prime or not? Output prints both a prime and not a prime

Tags: python, primes

```
#Enter an integer
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

#Prime number is a positive integer that is evenly divisible by 1 and itself
#Zero and one shouldn't be prime numbers

#Use for loop in the range of 2 as the first prime to any integer num
#If else statements: If integer num is divisible by any integer between
#2 and itself the integer num isn't a prime number
#or else the integer is a prime number

if num < 2:
    print(num, "isn't a prime number")

for x in range(2, num):
    if num % x == 0:
        print(num, "isn't a prime number")
        break
else:
    print(num, "is a prime number")
```

Observations -

The output I am getting when I enter the integer 0 and integer 1      individually, is:

```
0 isn't a prime number 
0 is a prim number
1 isn't a prime number
1 is a prime number
```

Keeping in mind this is with the `if` statement before the `for` loop. With it the entire program outputs every other integer correct. But still for integer 0 and 1:

It outputs:

```
0 is a prime number
1 is a prime number
```

Comment: Indentation problems. Should terminate if first `if` works.

Comment: You didn't indent the `for` loop and `else` block; Python `for` loops *also* can have a `else` block. It executes when you didn't use a `break` in the `for` loop, which your code makes use of here, but it still tells you that `0` and `1` are primes because the `for` loop is still run for those numbers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the `else` for the `for` makes sense. Wouldn't the cleaner solution with minimal changes be to quit in the first `if`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani: it would be, or the `for` loop with `else` would need to be indentented.

Comment: yes I had forgotten a for loop can be inputted in a for loop. I didn't realize an else statement was needed in order for it to run the for loop function instead of at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return when checking for `num < 2`. You could change to:

```
if num < 2:
    print(num, "isn't a prime number")
    return
```

assuming that you are in a function. Otherwise you could use `else`:

```
if num < 2:
    print(num, "isn't a prime number")
else:
    for x in range(2, num):
        if num % x == 0:
            print(num, "isn't a prime number")
            break
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
```

Comment: Yes the break is to ensure that the the operation ends when the integer isn't a prime number, otherwise it prints that it is bot a prime and not a prime

Comment: You may want to indent your final `else` block, otherwise it belongs to the `for` loop and not the `if`.

Comment: @BobChao87 It belongs to the `for`.  `For` can have an `else` in python.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor That is news to me! Good to know, this may be very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop once you've confirmed it's lower than `2`:

Use only **one** of the following ...

If you're looping, to continue to next iteration:

```
if num < 2:
    print(num, "isn't a prime number")
    continue
```

If you're in a function, and want to return a value:

```
if num < 2:
    print(num, "isn't a prime number")
    return False
```

If you're not looping or in a function, and want to terminate the program:

```
if num < 2:
    print(num, "isn't a prime number")
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a return statement or else clause after your initial IF condition.

Also just a quick tip, no need to check modulo of every integer up to the number.  I believe only up to half the number is necessary.  Been awhile since I programmed a prime number algorithm.

Comment: Up to (and including) the *floored square root* of the number is enough. E.g. it is enough to test up to 10 when testing for primes below 100, as 10 * 10 is already going to cover the whole range. You can also give the `range()` a step value of 2 and only test for odd numbers.

Comment: `for x in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):` and handle `2` separately.

Comment: the professor said not to use any math functions, so strictly logical.

Comment: the range has no defined limit but the number you input from user. hence why its
 for x in range (2, num):

Comment: @gabestanley: the professor probably meant not to use the `math` *module*. The `%` modulo operator is a 'math function' too if you cannot use the `**` power operator. MarkII and I mean that you can limit the upper limit of the range, there is no point in testing for 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 if you determined that 11 cannot be divided by 2 or 3, because 4 * 4 is going to be greater than 11 (2 * 4 and 3 * 4 were covered when you tested for divisibility by 2 and 3).

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, I meant from the math library. I saw other users online using the math library, that's what came to mind. Since he hasn't indicated a specific range, I just wanted it to be as big as it can be for testing purposes

Comment: @gabestanley: but there is *no point* in testing against all numbers below `n`, because you already know the answer by the time you get to the square root of n.